# Ajax Minifier (AjaxMin) - EvalTreatment for JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-ajax

So I was just minifying using the AjaxMin.dll in my project on every build/deployment for all js/css files with the **default** settings.  This turned out to be a bad idea.  One of the third party javascript files that we have has a nice eval statement with some variables or parameters being referenced.  When it gets minified, the original variables get renamed and not renamed in the eval statement.  This has caused a big old error in production (FML).

I have decided I need to pick safer settings for the minification process.

The documentation on AjaxMin is very ummm not clear.
http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/AjaxMinWithAndEval.ashx

Or maybe i just don't understand it.  I am using the code (with the DLL) and not the command line.

The `CodeSettings` class has a `EvalTreatment` class option but I am unsure what is the best option to pick...

From Microsoft (DLL source):

```
using System;

namespace Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities
{
    public enum EvalTreatment
    {
        Ignore = 0,
        MakeImmediateSafe = 1,
        MakeAllSafe = 2,
    }
}
```

I am thinking `MakeImmediateSafe`(1) or `MakeAllSafe`(2)?  What do you guys think?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I had a similar problem where i was using Ajax.Net (an old version of it) and i was minifying its common javascript which contained a line: `eval("r=" + ....` and I changed it to `r=eval("r=" + ...` which fixed it for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to make *absolutely sure* the minified results will *always* work, use the **MakeAllSafe** option. That will ensure no variables in the scope of the eval statement, nor in any parent scopes, will be renamed.

Comment: Yea I ended up doing that. Did CssComment.All as well for CommentMode on CSS.

You have made a truly amazing class library.  THANK YOU!.